# Remove horizontal scrolling in finder with big thumbnail view

Tags: finder, macos

This is an overflow problem. Like in this picture, there is two scrollbars, you need a horizontal + vertical scrolling ?
[image: thumbnail]

Is there a way to fix that ?

EDIT : I found a tip by using 'sort by name'.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you said, you can enable sorting files automatically by changing the Sort By or Arrange By mode from None to Name.

[image]

If others search for how to for example sort files by modification date without grouping them under these sections with horizontal scroll bars

[image]

you can set View > Arrange By to None and set View > Sort By (shown when holding option) to Date Modified.

[image]

Comment: Do you have to do this in every directory?!